# Change HDD partitions after installation

Tags: partitioning

I am new to Ubuntu.
I want to know how to re-partition my hard disk after installation.
I had used the `gnome-disks` application during install,
but now the HDD can't be unmounted as it contains the OS.
How can I revise the partition?
P.S I have tried [gparted](https://gparted.org/) but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

First, you might use your Ubuntu live CD/USB to make partitions changes on your bootable hard drive. You can make a number of online operations (I mean during you are on your system), but be sure to:

- Always umount partitions before formatting or deleting them.
- If you change hard drive layout (e.g. deleting partition) always prefer rebooting in order to allow a proper partition refresh in memory.

Comment: See https://opensource.com/article/18/6/how-partition-disk-linux